# Storing values to an array of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i have an object and i want to store some values from the frontend but I don't know how to select the tabs object to store the values from the frontend to mongoose, here is the code :

```
// modal
const dd = new mongoose.Schema({

  tabs: {
    title: { type: Array, required:true },
    content: { type: Array , required:true},
  },

})

// route
const { tabs } = req.body;
const taab = [];
    tabs.forEach(el => {
        taab.push({
            title : el.tabTitle,
            content : el.tabContent
        })
        
 });

let par = await dd.create({
   tabs: taab,
 })
```

I made a variable name taab and stored the values from the frontend but how can I store them inside **tabs** title and content inside mongoose ?

i tried `tabs : {title : taab.title , content: taab.content}` but it didn't work

Comment: Your model has two arrays, one for title and one for content. But when you populate it you provide it with one array of objects, each containing both title and content.

Comment: `tabs: [{ title: String, content: String }]`

Comment: i changed tabs model to String but it still not storing the values for the taab variable

Comment: @hoangdv thank you bro , your tip gave me the solution i had to make tabs an object of array of strings to be able to work ^^

Answer (score 0):

i changed the model to this and it worked :

```
tabs: {
    type: Object,
    title: [{ type: String, required:true }],
    content: [{ type: String , required:true}],
},
```